# Is here any in operator in Django ORM?

Tags: django, database, django-orm

In one of my projects I have a database table named `Doctor`. I can run query like:
`expected_doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(id=4)` or `expected_doctors = Doctor.objects.get(id=4)`. But how can I find doctors whose id is in [1,2,3,4,5];

Like :

```
expected_ids=[1,2,3,4,5]
expected_doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(id in expected_ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Doctor.objects.filter(id__in=expected_ids)
```

yes the `in` operator is there, which expects a `list of ids` to check within